# Making an asteroid explosion with asteroid bits

Tags: cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, particles

How do I make the asteroid explode with small bits exploding outward?

I'd need a texture animation for the asteroid cracking, but I'm not sure how to use the particle emitter to have random sized asteroid bits fly out.

And would these bits collide and bounce off other objects?

http://www.startalkradio.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/asteroid-and-white-dwarf.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make multiple emitters each with its own texture.  That would diversify the particles.  Spritekit particles dont have physics properties so no.. they wouldnt bounce around.  You'd need to use a collection of regular sprites if you want that effect.

Comment: Won't multiple emitters eat up memory? Especially if i have multiple exploding asteroids?

Comment: it depends how many particles you have per emitter.. and also how long you keep them around (remove from parent after effect is over)..  theres no way to have multiple textures for one emitter.